# Editing Button Label In Document Outline

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to edit the button names in the document outline- it usually works by clicking on the button and then retyping a new name. It won't allow me to do this anymore ever since upgrading to Xcode 8.1. However, sometimes when I click a bunch of times it randomly allows me to retype a new name. I've been able to retype "snailButton" and "rabbitButton", but I still need to rename the other buttons I have.

How can I fix this so I can retype? Thanks[image: ![Screenshot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcxPI.png)

Answer (score 2):

You actually have two options here:

Steps for Option 1

1 - You single click on the element you want to edit, it should be highlighted with blue at this point.

2 - give it a second or two, then click on the highlighted element again and you should see that it is now

Steps for Option 2

1 - You single click on the element you want to edit, it should be highlighted with blue at this point.

2 - Hit enter on your keyboard after a second or two and you should see that it is now

A small video to demonstrate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5S1He3Jvics

First two times are Option 1 and the last 1 is Option 2.